# Unable to store element in scala collection

Tags: scala, list, playframework

I am trying to add the result of database to List. But I have one problem here. Elements are added to list and size is same as number of element at initial size. But while printing final size, it's always 0. I'm not sure what is the error.

Thanks in advance

```
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  var result = ListBuffer[Item]()
  val res = db.run(items.result)
  for (r <- res) {
    for (r1 <- r) {
      result += r1
    }
    println("initial size = " + result.size)
  }
  /**
    * Create an Action to render an HTML page.
    *
    * The configuration in the `routes` file means that this method
    * will be called when the application receives a `GET` request with
    * a path of `/`.
    */
  def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>

    println("final size = " + result.size)

    Ok(views.html.index())
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `res` is not `empty` and the `for` is getting exectued?

Comment: yes...printing inside loop displays the values it holds

Comment: Could you also log raw `result`? The question is whether it is the same object both times. As your code is not really a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is hard to guess but I bet that somehow those are different things. P.S. by logging "raw `result`" I mean logging something like `System.identityHashCode(result)`

Comment: that's giving the same output

Comment: I have failed in my attempts to replicate this behaviour.

Comment: @ramzavil, you mean that if you change your code to `println("initial size = " + result.size + " " + System.identityHashCode(result))` and `println("final size = " + result.size + " " + System.identityHashCode(result))` you get the same `hashCode` both times but the "final size" is `0`? If this is the case, you should look for a piece of code that clears the `result`. Also try changing the type of `result` to `immutable.List` that you initialize from your now temporary `ListBuffer`. This will show you all the place where you actually mutate the `result`